# How to move Android Studio's Device Manager on Mac OS to external SSD?

Tags: macos, android-studio

My goal is to move the Android Studio app to the external SSD:

1. To reduce the storage space used in the Mac Mini M1.

The problem is while I am able to move the `Android SDK Location`, I don't know how to change the setting for the `~/.android` folder. Which is the location for the AVD.

What I've did:

1. Format the external SSD to "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)"
2. Move the Android Studio app to the external SSD.
3. Move the `~/Library/Android/sdk` folder to the external SSD.
4. Change the `Android SDK Location` to the external SSD from the menu `Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`.
5. Move the `~/.android` folder to the external SSD.
   **6. I don't know how to change the setting for the `~/.android` folder**